# MVC6 Object being returned with a null value for one if its state object

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am missing some key info here.. It should be simple yet I cannot get it to work. I have looked at various tutorials on navigational properties and it appears I have set this up correctly for Code First.

I have a POCO class with one element being a relationship to a state POCO class thus:

```
public class CompanyDetail
{
    public int CompanyDetailId { get; set; }
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    public string CompanyStreet1 { get; set; }
    public string CompanyStreet2 { get; set; }
    public string Suburb { get; set; }
    public string Postcode { get; set; }

    public virtual State State { get; set; }
}

public class State
{
    [Key]
    public int StateId { get; set; }
    public string ShortName { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<CompanyDetail> CompanyDetails { get; set; }
}
```

States were loaded first.

I then loaded one record into the database that includes a state.

I then go and retrieve the record using:

```
var Company = _context.CompanyDetails.First();
```

It retreives everything except the state which has a value of NULL - its not loading the state.

```
CompanyName = "Test Company"
CompanyStreet1 = "76"
CompanyStreet2 = "Test Street"
Postcode = "4000"
State = null
```

Checking the database again and the state reference is there..

what am I missing? I should have the state in the retrieved data...

Comment: Your `CompanyDetail` model needs a `public int StateId { get; set; }` property (the FK relationship)

Comment: Thanks Stephen.  I now have the ID returned but state is still null.. is that alway how this works that you use the stateId and the actual value "public virtual State State { get; set }" will always be null when you do a retireval. I can certainly use the id just curious about the other..

Comment: Try `var Company = _context.CompanyDetails.Include(x => x.State).First();`

Comment: Am getting an error on the Include...

Comment: It was "does not contain a definition for 'Include' and no extension method" and I then realised I needed to add "using Microsoft.Data.Entity;" ..my mistake. your input is really appreciated.